# Linear algebra text recommendation for math competition

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a Linear algebra book with some purposes. Basically, I want to review whole concepts appeared in undergraduate linear algebra, prepare for math competition, and especially, train myself like a master of linear algebra. Just to let you know, I had studied linear algebra through Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra 3 years ago. Of course, I've already tried to review this topic via the same book, however, this book is too lengthy and boring that I started to look for new books. Below is a summary about what I mentioned:

-Studied lienar algebra through Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra

-Looking for other book with some requirements:

1. Review whole concept in linear algebra quickly
2. Contain interesting and good exercises.
3. Prepare for undergraduate math competition

You can recommend any books which satisfy only one or two requirements in the list.

Comment: The Art Of Problem Solving site has books dedicated to math competition in linear algebra. Also check out linear algebra inequalities by Henrik Mink-a classic Dover book.

Answer (score 0):

Linear algebra - Stephen H. Friedberg

Linear algebra - Serge Lang

Answer (score 0):

Putnam And Beyond. 30 pages (60-90) address the all linear algebra chapters and every problem is quite illustrative